# Subscript operator with variable or how to cut the end-of-line characters?

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I have an expression in Jenkinsfile:

```
myvar = myvar.substring(0, myvar.length() - 2)
```

The goal is to cut the EoL characters from the string (which contains the execution result of the batch command).

Recently I've installed GroovyLint plugin for VSCode and it complained about this line:

> Violation in class None. The String.substring(int, int) method can be replaced with the subscript operatorGroovyLint(UnnecessarySubstring-1)

I've googled what is that subscript operator and it looks like the replacement would be something like this:

```
myvar = myvar[0..myvar.length() - 2]
```

but unfortunately, it does not work: it gives no visible error, but also makes no changes to the myvar.

What do I miss? Maybe you can't use variables as part of the subscript operator?

Maybe there is a better way to cut those end-of-line characters? I guess I could use regexp, but to me, that sounds like overkill.

Thanks!

Comment: What is your groovy version? And in what environment did you try this? `groovysh`?

Comment: My groovy version is 2.4.12. Not sure what you mean under 'environment'? That script is run by Jenkins is run on Windows Home.

Comment: I was going to post an answer, but I can't reproduce this even on groovy 2.4. Maybe that's because of minor versions... But please try any of these, it should work: `myvar[0..<-2]`, `myvar[0..-3]`, `myvar[0..(myvar.length()-2)]`. When you use a range, the upper bound is inclusive, unlike the behavior of `String.substring()`. That's unless it's half-open, like the `myvar[0..<-2]` example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to ernset_k, found the answer!

The problem was that the subscript operator includes the upper bound. In my original scenario, last 2 characters where not printable and that's why I did not see the difference while debugging. I had to use "myvar.length()-3".

But as indicated by ernest_k, instead of calculating the length of the string you need to trim, we can also use other options of the operator. All these examples work as expected:

```
println myvar[0..myvar.length() - 3]
println myvar[0..<-2]
println myvar[0..-3]
```